# PROBLEMS WITH SEO MAGENTO 2 SAME URL FOR DIFFERENT STORE VIEWS

Tags: product, url, seo

I have one magento 2 with two stores (two different domains ) each store with two store viewS (english and spanish) both stores share almost the same products. Each store have the same URL for the products for the store views...
Google Search is not showing any result from the english store view of one of the stores. Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As an option, you can add store view code to URLs by switching setting Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Url Options > Add Store Code to Urls to 'Yes'